# How to render the api call only when there is some change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

#In below code :  I have used useEffect hook. In that I am calling apiData()(it has array of objects coming from api).
From API we are getting id, name, parent name, isActive. isActive is mapped with toggle which changes. I need to update the changes and retrive it. so I have used products. But because of this the whole data is called again and again. Is there any other way of solving this issue. #

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const transformData = (data) => {
    return data.map((item) => ({
      id: item.structureId,
      name: item.name,
      parent: item.parentName,
      isActive: item.isActive,
    }));
  };
 useEffect(() => {
    apiData()
      .then((data) => {
        const transformedData = transformData(data);
        setProducts(transformedData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error in fetching data:", error));
  }, [products, transformData]);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't need to add `products` to the array that you send to `useEffect`.

Comment: isActive is mapped with toggle which changes. I need to update the changes and retrive it. If I remove products from array How can I do this. @EmilKarlsson

Comment: The problem is that I don't really understand what you mean, and considering that you've been downvoted by multiple people, neither does anyone else. Do you mean that you have a checkbox, and you need to call the API each time the checkbox changes its value? The way you've written your question, I can't interpret exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> isActive is mapped with toggle which changes. I need to update the changes and retrive it.

Do you mean that you need to constantly check the API for updates? Because if you do, then you need to use something like [EventStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (or possibly [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)). But that requires changes to both the frontend AND the backend. You can't just resend the same API call over and over again, because that would be a large (and unnecessary) strain on the backend.

Comment: isActive is mapped with toggle which changes. I need to update the changes and retrive it. Exactly this is what I meant. Any Other soln other than [EventStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) @emil-karlsson